# span id getting undefined

Tags: jquery

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nWfFQ/2/)

```
 $(".csstablelisttd").live('mousedown', function (e)
        {    var rowIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
           var colIndex = $(e.target).closest('td').index();
            alert($('.csstextheader').eq(rowIndex).find('td').eq(colIndex).find('span').attr('id'));
        });
```

//I have to find span id on click of cell having rowIndex and colIndex respectively.
getting me undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `.eq(rowIndex)`.

```
alert($('.csstextheader').find('td').eq(colIndex).find('span').attr('id'));
```

Comment: i want to select header span id

Comment: @nathan, if you have comments to make on a tag please by all means to so but bring it up on [meta]; don't edit the tags themselves.

Comment: @ben, sorry about that, I wasn't sure where that type of thing usually went.